# Why can't I directly call method in the binder class?

Tags: java, android

I was reading the documentation for bound services on android and I stumble upon the following code  on the documentation:

```
public class LocalService extends Service {
    // Binder given to clients
    private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();
    // Random number generator
    private final Random mGenerator = new Random();

    /**
     * Class used for the client Binder.  Because we know this service always
     * runs in the same process as its clients, we don't need to deal with IPC.
     */
    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        LocalService getService() {
            // Return this instance of LocalService so clients can call public methods
            return LocalService.this;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mBinder;
    }

    /** method for clients */
    public int getRandomNumber() {
      return mGenerator.nextInt(100);
    }
}
```

and

```
public class BindingActivity extends Activity {
    LocalService mService;
    boolean mBound = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        // Bind to LocalService
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, LocalService.class);
        bindService(intent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        // Unbind from the service
        if (mBound) {
            unbindService(mConnection);
            mBound = false;
        }
    }

    /** Called when a button is clicked (the button in the layout file attaches to
      * this method with the android:onClick attribute) */
    public void onButtonClick(View v) {
        if (mBound) {
            // Call a method from the LocalService.
            // However, if this call were something that might hang, then this request should
            // occur in a separate thread to avoid slowing down the activity performance.
            int num = mService.getRandomNumber();
            Toast.makeText(this, "number: " + num, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    /** Defines callbacks for service binding, passed to bindService() */
    private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className,
                IBinder service) {
            // We've bound to LocalService, cast the IBinder and get LocalService instance
            LocalBinder binder = (LocalBinder) service;
            mService = binder.getService();
            mBound = true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
            mBound = false;
        }
    };
}
```

What strikes me as odd was that why is the method getRandomNumber() not be included in the LocalBinder class. This way you can just use the binder to call method to be perform(getRandomNumber()) rather than having to call the LocalBinder to return the service with getService() and then using the service to call the getRandomNumber(). This extra step of returning the service to call getRandomNumber() doesn't make sense to me so can anyone explain to me why this is the case?

Comment: of course you can define any number of methods inside your `LocalBinder`, not only `getService`

Comment: hey thanks for answering. However I am sill not so sure why does the documentation use the getservice() way. There has to be a good reason for this

Comment: see https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html#Binder, they say: `contains public methods that the client can call`, pay attention on **methods**

Comment: I think you didn't understand my question too well. What I mean is if you can have any custom method that the client will use be inside a binder subclass then why do you need to put that method outside the binder subclass in the first place. As by putting the method outside of the binder subclass and in the service class complicates things because now you need to do an extra step of getting the service and then calling the method you want instead of just calling it straight through the binder subclass. So why is this an option when clearly there is another option where it is more efficient.

Comment: in the link i posted they say you can do that in three different ways depending on your current architecture / setup, read the step #1 `In your service, create an instance of Binder that either:`

Comment: yah I know I saw that but like I said do you know why the other option of getting the service is even listed when calling the method through the binder saves you the trouble of needing to return the service and then using the service to call the method?

Comment: you can think of returning a service is like `or, returns an instance of another class hosted by the service with public methods the client can call` which can be useful in some cases, again its better if you have more options than just one

Comment: ok I think I know where you are going and I understand it now thanks.